# Firefox and IE render table background-color differently

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-tables

While Firefox (54.0) renders the attached code as a red bar over a blue background, IE (11 and Edge) renders the red bar *behind* the blue background.

Is there any way to make IE paint the bar *over* the background, just as FF does?

This HTML code has been reduced as far as possible to show the problem. Originally it is from a web app showing events on a calendar with the blue background marking special days (weekend/holidays).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 30px;
}

div {
  height: 10px
}

.b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width:250px;background-color:red">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="b"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try adding `position: relative` to the `div` - like this `<div style="width:250px;background-color:red; position: relative;">`

Comment: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: @cktang what has that got to do with anything?

Comment: It makes all browsers render consistently, and is pretty standard

Comment: @cktang That's a big library to include when just adding `position:relative` can just fix the issue at hand

Answer (score 0):

If Edge cannot show the same color as Firefox, try to use color written in HEX format.

Just re-write your code:

```
 .b {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

To HEX color code:

```
    .b {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Otherwise you can define special CSS for each browser, this is for MS Edge:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .selector {
        property: value;
    }
}
```

Or for Firefox:

```
 <style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
</style>
```

Hope it helps.

//EDIT: For that background / foreground try to use Z-Index value in CSS